# How can i zip() two lists together without the output having "\n" at the beginning of every second element?

Tags: python, list, python-zip

I currently have two lists

```py
songlist = []
artistlist = []
```

I return

```py
list(zip(songlist, artistlist))
```

and it gives me what I want(a 3d list of a 2d list containing each song title and respective artist) but before each second item in each list is "\n"

for example a list in the 3d list would look like: ["Amarillo By Morning","\nGeorge Strait"]

I'm gonna be using the artist in a later function so I'd rather there not be the \n there.

instead of my above code i tried returning a variable containing:

```py
[i + j for i, j in zip(songlist, artistlist)]
```

but that just returned: `["Amarillo By Morning\nGeorge Strait", ... cont`.

Comment: Please provide a [mre]. What does your data look like?

Comment: `zip()` isn't doing that, it must be in the list data. Did you read these lists from a file? The file has `\n` at the end of each line, you need to remove it when putting the values into the lists.

Comment: you may try `list(zip(songlist, map(str.strip,artistlist)))` for instance, to apply removal of whitespace on all artists

Comment: But when you read from a file, `\n` is at the end. I have no idea how you're getting it at the beginning. We need to see some code.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid making another iterator, you can just modify each `artist` as they come along, if you can't modify it at the source.

Also, return a list instead of using string concatenation if you want a list.

```py
[[song, artist.strip()] for song, artist in zip(songlist, artistlist)]
```